# Using the value of one cell to GOTO the cell of that value

Tags: worksheet-function

I'm trying to use a cell that holds the address of another cell as text. I want the macro to use the text in the 1st cell (the value of the cell) to GOTO that cell named.

[image: Sheet area look]

I thought I could trick the Macro recorder by selecting that 1st cell and using F5 (GOTO) but there are two problems.

[image: Trying F5 GOTO function]

The optional cells listed seem quite random and are not my text value, and the target box of the GOTO form only seems to accept absolute fixed cell addresses (like $B505) and will not accept a variable (or the value of the cell) that holds the dynamic address.

1. Answer to question from harrymc: the cell on sheet 2 is K48. It keeps the location on sheet 1 ((Balance Sheet) where next month is to be loaded. That value in K48 is dynamic and changes from month to month. For example if the value of K48 is "Balance Sheet!$B505", I want the macro to GOTO that cell.
2. Answer to jsotola: GOTO is an excel function that allows you to jump to the specified cell. In my case the cell I want is different every month. The cell address is maintained in sheet 2's cell K48. When I run this macro I need a way to jump to the cell on sheet 1, depending on the cell contents (name/location) stored in sheet 2's K48 cell. It is similar to indirect addressing.

Comment: It's unclear which cell values are to be used to select which cells?

Comment: what do you mean by `GOTO`? ... why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
Sub jumpToCell()
Dim aAddress() As String
    aAddress = Split([Sheet2!K48].Text, "!")
    Application.Goto Reference:=Worksheets(aAddress(0)).Range(aAddress(1))
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, this works Yea.... I did have to add a command to make sure sheet 2 (containing my K48 cell) was active because the Split function it did not seem to like the sheet reference in front of the K48 cell name. 


Sub jumpToCell()
Dim aAddress() As String
    Sheets("Next Month Bills").Select
    Range("B1").Select
    aAddress = Split([$K$48].Text, "!")
    Application.Goto Reference:=Worksheets(aAddress(0)).Range(aAddress(1))
End Sub